# How to find most common combination in R

Tags: r, combinations

I am working with some league of legends data and I want to find the most common combination of champions in wins or losses. So Game1B (blue) and Game2R (red) both had annie and blitzcrank, and that team won both times. Over two games obviously it is easy to see, but I want to automate it to do it over about 90-100 games.

I have two issues with it right now :

-Too many combinations
When I run the combination, it spits out 45 combinations.
There should be two instances of Annie and Blitzcrank as they were picked together twice, but it shows 
Annie Blitz : 3 times
Blitz Annie : 1 time

-I am not sure how to go from having the 45 columns to finding the most played combination.
I tried using sort() on the combination, but it removed the actual combination.

```
    Game1B   Game1R Game2B     Game2R
1          W        L      L          W
2      Annie     Bard   Bard      Annie
3 Blitzcrank    Braum  Braum Blitzcrank
4      Yuumi  Caitlyn Anivia     Viktor
5     Ezreal     Ashe  Talon      Elise
6       Azir Volibear   Sett   Renekton

FactorTestA <- c()
FactorTestB <- c()
FactorTestA[1:5] <- as.character(LoL2$Game1B[2:6])
FactorTestB[1:5] <- as.character(LoL2$Game2R[2:6])
FactorTest <- FactorTestA; FactorTest[6:10] <- FactorTestB

CombinationChamps <- combn(FactorTest, 2)
```

Comment: I'm confused by your text. I assume the data you show is sample input? What is your desired output for that sample input? And the data you show is for... 2 games, played by two teams? How does your data structure generalize up - normally data is organized with observations in rows and variables in columns, but you say something about "45 columns" which makes me think you're bucking convention.

Comment: @Indescribled Are you looking for something like `rev(sort(table(FactorTest)))`?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reorganizing your data. I would think something like: 1 row per game. Column are `game_id` (and a  `match id`, if there are usually several games per match), `win_champs` a list column with a character vector of the winning team's champions, `lose_champs`, a list column with a character vector of the winning team's champions, and perhaps other columns (date? score? not sure what other data you have). The [tidy data paper/vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/tidy-data.html) would be a good read to understand why this data structure makes more sense.